# How to set the default attribute for a product programmatically in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a script that loops through my woocommerce shop and set the default product attribute for any product that has a size variation to the first option. I found this method that I assumed would do the trick https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Product.html#method_set_default_attributes

Here is my code. I've got this function firing on the wp_footer action and I'm just trying to get it to work on one product page before making a wp_query and running it across all the products.

```
function set_default_attribute()
{
    if(is_product() ) {
        $_product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
        $product_attributes = $_product->get_attributes();

        if (isset($product_attributes["size"])) {
          $first_size_attribute = $product_attributes['size']['options'][0];
          $attribute_array = array();
          $attribute_array["size"] = $first_size_attribute;
          $_product->set_default_attributes($attribute_array);
        }else {
          echo "no size attribute";
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it nothing happens $_product->set_default_attributes() doesn't give any errors or return anything. Is this the proper use of this method? I can't find any info on it other than what is in the woocommerce docs

Comment: are you calling the function after declaring it?

Comment: yes the function is running on the wp_footer action like this:
```
add_action("wp_footer", "set_default_attribute");
```
and then i'm just navigating to product pages that I'm trying to test the code on. My actual code has a bunch of echo statements and print_r's that i didn't include in my above code because I thought it would be confusing